NestJS Create Reusable/Publishable Library For any Node Js Framework
I want to create a Nest.js Package, so I can reuse a controller in multiple Nest.js/express js/Next-js projects.
I have checked out https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries but that doesn't seem to be what I was looking for because it seems to that it is only possible to import the library within the repo.
What the best way to have a library that could be published via npm so I can install and import it in other Node js Projects irrespective of the framework type in Node-js?
